# How to get SHA1 and MD5 checksum from HttpPostedFileBase file.InputStream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, checksum

I want to get the checksum of uploaded file in MVC.

Currently I am doing this

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, string path)
{


    if (file != null)
    {

        string checksumMd5    = HashGenerator.GetChecksum(file.InputStream, HashGenerator.MD5);;
        string checksumSha1   = HashGenerator.GetChecksum(file.InputStream, HashGenerator.SHA1);

   //other logic follows....

    }
```

but when I do following in Console app and read file from File path then,

```
string path = @"C:\Users\anandv4\Desktop\Manifest-5977-681-673.txt";

var md5hash = HashGenerator.GetChecksum(path, HashGenerator.MD5);
var sha1 = HashGenerator.GetChecksum(path, HashGenerator.SHA1);
```

the values of both are different.

Code for generating hash :

```
public static string GetChecksum(string fileName, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileName), 1000000))
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(algorithm.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}

public static string GetChecksum(Stream stream, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    using (stream)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(algorithm.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me what is the difference between the two. Utlimately both the methods resolve to Stream in *GetChecksum* method

Comment: Aside from anything else, it's "rude" of your `GetChecksum` method accepting a stream to have a `using` statement that disposes of the stream - if you're being passed the stream from somewhere else, you almost certainly shouldn't dispose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are hashing a stream, **you need to set the current position of the stream to 0 before computing the hash**.

```
file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

For me, this is a great place for an extension method, eg.:

```
//compute hash using extension method:
string checksumMd5    = file.InputStream.GetMD5hash();
```

Which is supported by the class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public static class Extension_Methods
{

    public static string GetMD5hash(this Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var md5Instance = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            var hashResult = md5Instance.ComputeHash(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hashResult).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }

}
```